# Graphing Intergration in Python

Tags: python

In the following code I have implemented Simpsons Rule in Python. I have attempted to plot the absolute error as a function of n for a suitable range of integer values n. I know that the exact result should be 1-cos(pi/2). However my graph doesn't seem to be correct. How can I fix my code to get the correct output? there were two loops and I don't think I implemented my graph coding correctly

```
def simpson(f, a, b, n):
    """Approximates the definite integral of f from a to b by the composite Simpson's rule, using n subintervals (with n even)"""

    h = (b - a) / (n)
    s = f(a) + f(b)

    diffs = {}

    for i in range(1, n, 2):
        s += 4 * f(a + i * h)
    for i in range(2, n-1, 2):
        s += 2 * f(a + i * h)

    r = s
    exact = 1 - cos(pi/2)
    diff = abs(r  - exact)
    diffs[n] = diff

    ordered = sorted(diffs.items())
    x,y = zip(*ordered)
    plt.autoscale()
    plt.loglog(x,y)
    plt.xlabel("Intervals")
    plt.ylabel("Error")
    plt.show()
    return s * h / 3

simpson(lambda x: sin(x), 0.0, pi/2, 100)
```

[image]

Comment: It appears that you are only calculating `diffs` for one value of `n`. So your plot will only have one point, not a line. Is that your intention?

Comment: If you add a `marker` to your `plt.loglog` call, you will see that one point. Try `plt.loglog(x,y, marker="o")`.

Comment: I am trying to have it a line not just a single point

Comment: would you be able to help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `simpson` method should just calculate the integral for a single value of `n` (as it does), but creating the plot for many values of `n` should be outside that method. as:

```
from math import pi, cos, sin
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def simpson(f, a, b, n):
    """Approximates the definite integral of f from a to b by the composite Simpson's rule, using 2n subintervals """

    h = (b - a) / (2*n)
    s = f(a) + f(b)


    for i in range(1, 2*n, 2):
        s += 4 * f(a + i * h)
    for i in range(2, 2*n-1, 2):
        s += 2 * f(a + i * h)
    return s * h / 3


diffs = {}
exact = 1 - cos(pi/2)
for n in range(1, 100):
    result = simpson(lambda x: sin(x), 0.0, pi/2, n)
    diffs[2*n] = abs(exact - result)   # use 2*n or n here, your choice.


ordered = sorted(diffs.items())
x,y = zip(*ordered)
plt.autoscale()
plt.loglog(x,y)
plt.xlabel("Intervals")
plt.ylabel("Error")
plt.show()
```

Comment: also in your code in result = … should the n be 2*n? or not?

Comment: If you use `simpson(lambda x: sin(x), 0.0, pi/2, 100)`, then the `simpson` method would actually use 200 intervals (due to the `2*n` in the `simpson` method).

Comment: The `2*n` is already in the `simpson` method. If you put `2*n` in the call to the `simpson` method you would actually be using `4n`.

Comment: how would I add an additional plot of n vs n^(-4)?

Comment: That's a separate question. Please post a new question with your code so far to solve the new question.

Comment: just posted it!